# How can I handle relational data in machine learning classification?

Tags: machine-learning

I am trying to classify some incidents as True positive and False positives using machine learning.

I have a dataset of incidents where every column describes an attribute of the incident. And there's a list of alerts associated with each incident.
The list of alerts can contain 0-10 alerts with every alert row having details of that alert. i.e there is a one to many relationship between an incident and alerts.

I have some experience in classifying simple datasets which have set of columns for every row but I am not sure how to handle relational data like this.

I am using scikit-learn to for this.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your data looks like this:

```
incident table:
id | i_attr0 | alerts
0  | foo     | [alert0, alert1]
...

alert table:
id     | a_attr0
alert0 | bar
alert1 | baz
...
```

If that is the case I would denormalize the table to something like:

```
incident-alert table:
id | i_attr0 | alert0 | alert0_a_attr0 | alert1 | alert1_a_attr0 | etc..
0  | foo     | true   | bar            | true   | baz            |
```

and then work from there.